# How can I keep the 2 arrows for the easy fancybox gallery in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I would like to know how can I keep the 2 arrows in the gallery images on the website that I'm working on. I have tried a few tricks and I cannot get it to work. Thanks in advance...

[Image gallery plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqxAI.jpg)
here is the Link of the site: http://dev.fpm3.com/veriform.ca/parts-fabrication/carbon-steel-fabrication/

Comment: What were the few tricks that you tried?

Comment: I tried to add the arrow with jquery but the link wasn't working. We ended up switching the arrows. Because they were inverted. Thanks for the comment @EricHauenstein I appreciate your help and interest.